# vanilla bootstrap in react tooltip issue

Tags: reactjs, bootstrap-4, tooltip

I am using vanilla bootstrap and do not intend to move to react-bootstrap due to unnecessarily changes that they did.

My problem is that some times the style of the tooltip gone (black nice tooltip with white text becomes white background with black text which is pure default html tooltip). It is very random and basically I have the below code in my hook. Anyone has the same issue?

```
componentDidMount(){
 $(function(){ $('[data-toggle="tooltip"]').tooltip()})
}
```

Answer (score 0):

This error may be occuring due to alignment of the code in html page. I would suggest you to use inline script tag by creating on React.

```
componentDidMount(){
    const s = document.createElement('script');
    s.type = 'text/javascript';
    //s.async = true;
    s.innerHTML = `$(function(){ $('[data-toggle="tooltip"]').tooltip()})`;
    this.containerRef.appendChild(s);
}
render(){
  return (
       <div ref={(element)=>(this.containerRef = element )}>
        ...
       </div>
         )
}
```

Comment: @cangokceasian Thanks My problem is that the tooltip should be shown for a huge dropdown button lists. So I could not make a ref for each of them.

Comment: You just add the reference to your container which contains the tooltips. It will create a script tag filled with the code and it will work for each tooltip. So you create once and make it work for each child.

Comment: Do you mean all the children will be inherit such style from their parent?

Comment: Yeah normally it will because you are using the query from attribute data-toggle. If you have N tooltip the script will catch all N tooltip and start with method .toolTip(). It will run all of them.

Comment: So in my parent container I also need to add data-toggle?

Comment: Nope, data-toggle is added to your tooltips. Tooltips will be below the container. If you add the inline script tag to end of the container, it will start the tooltips with no problem.

Comment: I am using typescript also. It is really a mess. It looks it does not work for me. by the way in your code this.containerRef.appendChild(s); should not be as this.containerRef.current.appendChild(s); ? because appendChild is a method for node rather than HTMLDivElement

Comment: What we are adding to the render's div container is script node. It looks pretty simple solution to me.

Comment: For me it is sucks actually. I am using Async (react-async) in order to load the data of the dropdown menu. I make a UI and all the loaded items from server goes as a child of Ul. All il have tooltip. One of the problem is that in componentDidMount, the reference is not available. I think it is related to Async. Basically two times componentDidMount loaded ( one when the app loads and the other when Async fires) but in none of the cases my reference is attached to the Ul element

Comment: You better check your browser's developer console for errors. I think that something wrong in your code occurs and you js command is not working. I cant go deeper at that point.

Comment: I think my problem is related to react-async life cycle hook actually. Do you know how could I have access to life cycle of react-async? I tested componentDidMount and componentDidUpdate but none of them triggered by react-async full-filled. basically I want to update the state when the react-async fullfilled.